# mongo - cli drops with Failed to mlock: Cannot allocate locked memory

Tags: mongodb, fedora, systemd-nspawn

```
[root@host project]# mongo
2021-06-01T04:51:34.325+0200 F  -        [main] Failed to mlock: Cannot allocate locked memory. For more details see: https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/cannot-allocate-locked-memory: Operation not permitted
2021-06-01T04:51:34.325+0200 F  -        [main] Fatal Assertion 28832 at src/mongo/base/secure_allocator.cpp 255
2021-06-01T04:51:34.325+0200 F  -        [main] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Using Fedora in nspawn container.

Unfortunately the link is also broken.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a similar problem. I have a Debian nspawn container with Docker inside. The `mongo` image failed to launch because `mlock` system calls were denied.

I had the following configuration in my `/etc/systemd/nspawn/machine.nspawn`:

```
[Exec]
Capability=all
SystemCallFilter=add_key keyctl

[Files]
Bind=/sys/fs/cgroup
```

I solved my problem by adding `@memlock` to `SystemCallFilter`.

In your case, if you don't have a `Capability=all` line in your `machine.nspawn` file, you need to have at least `Capability=CAP_IPC_LOCK`.

Comment: Works. Thank you.